# How to explode an array column in spark java with dataset

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a Dataset in spark java as:
**Current:**

```
+--------------+--------------------+
|          x   |               YS.   |
+--------------+--------------------+
|x1            |   [Y1,Y2]          |
|x2            |   [Y3]             |
```

I want to explode this Dataset and convert the array in to individual entry as"

```
Desired:

+--------------+--------------------+
|          x   |    YS.   
+--------------+--------------------+
|x1            |   Y1          
|X1            |.  Y2
|x2            |   Y3
```

I read the table from database and read the two column but unable to use the explode functionality.

```
DS = reader.option("table", "dummy").load()
                .select(X,YS).explode(??)
```

How should I use the explode and get the desired Dataset  with Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the principle, you need to select a **new** column (not the `YS` column), where the **value** of the new column will be an exploded `YS` column value.

Starting from the code from the question, this would be something like:

```
ds = reader.option("table", "dummy").load()
ds = ds.select(ds.col("X"), explode(ds.col("YS")).as("Y"))
```

Here is the API doc: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.6/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#explode-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-

Comment: I am using spark_sql_2.11 and have 
`"use flatMap() or select() with functions.explode() instead", "2.0.0"`
How do we use select() with functions.explode?